# Make RadEditor invisible in RadGrid

Tags: radgrid

I have a Radgrid call Grid1.
Inside the RadGrid I like to make a field RadEditor invisible programatically

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Description" FilterControlAltText="Filter Description column"
 HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" UniqueName="Description">
<EditItemTemplate>
   <telerik:RadEditor StripFormattingOnPaste="MSWord" ID="LimitEdit" runat="server" Content='<%# Bind("Description") %>'
                            Skin="Windows7">
   </telerik:RadEditor>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

I tried the following code but did not seem to work:

```
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {

            var gridItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            if ("ActionItems".Equals(e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name))
            {                 


                var radEditor = editItem.FindControl("LimitEdit") as RadEditor;
                radEditor.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

When I do the above code it says that it cannot find LimitEdit

Comment: Could you please provide (grid's) full mark up (aspx page) code?

Comment: Jayesh I sent it over to you.